# Class `__init__` with decorator invoked on import

Tags: python, decorator

I have a decorator that helps define class attributes coming from a global configuration file. The function looks as such:

```py
config_data = {
    "resourceA": {"a": "foo", "b": "bar"},
    "resourceB": {"x": "baz", "y": "boo"}
}

def autoinit(resource: str = None, data: dict = config_data, **kwargs):
    print(f'here for {resource}')
    if not kwargs:
        if resource:
            kwargs = data[resource]  # get defaults

    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **configs):
            kwargs.update(configs)  # update kwargs with overrides
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped

    return wrapper
```

This decorator acts in such a way that if I have a class:

```py
class ResourceA:
    @autoinit(resource="resourceA")
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    # other stuff

class ResourceB:
    @autoinit(resource="resourceB")
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    # other stuff
```

will be automatically set from the data config.

Now, when I perform an import

```
from module.submodule import ResourceA
```

I result with:

```
here for resourceA
here for resourceB
```

Why does the decorator get invoked when I have not yet instantiated the class?

This is a dummied version of the real problem I am having.  It is interrupting my testing, as `data: dict = config_data` is actually being loaded from a default file.  When I run my tests, there exists a version where the default file does not exist, but I cannot get passed it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: um, because that is how a decorator works.  *the decorator* get's invoked when... you invoke it! i.e. `@autoinit`, which is equivalent to `def __init__(self,) ...; __init__ = autoinit(__init__)`. Your decorator returns a wrapper, and *that* gets invoked when you instantiate the class.

Comment: On import the classes are created and the method definitions in it are executed (not the code of the methods itself) to register the functions as methods. This also includes decorators, if present.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, want to post that as the answer?

Comment: @DanielWalker I mean, honestly, this is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: So by importing I am invoking? If you can help guide me through an answer I would really appreciate it.  I thought it would only be invoked if I have instantiated it.  How else can I implement this?

Comment: @sgerbhctim yes, when you import a module, the class definitions in the global scope execute (everything that is in the global scope executes), and you invoke your decorator in the class definition.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how would you modify this design?

Comment: @sgerbhctim Move the four lines below `def autoinit` to under `def wrapper`

Comment: You should post it as an answer.  I haven't found a duplicate yet and, even if it is one, you'll still get the reputation for it.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon thank you so much, if you want to put as answer, i will accept

Answer (score 0):

Can modify the decorator function as such:

```
def autoinit(resource: str = None, data: dict = config_data, **kwargs):

    def wrapper(func):

        def wrapped(*args, **configs):

            nonlocal kwargs

            if not kwargs:
                if resource:
                    kwargs = data[resource]

            kwargs.update(configs)  # update kwargs with overrides
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped

    return wrapper
```

Comment: I meant between `def wrapper` and `def wrapped`; the idea is for these lines to not execute upon `autoinit` being invoked, but instead upon `__init__` being invoked.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason nothing is printing in this version is because you removed the `print` calls, not because you actually delayed things the way you wanted them delayed.

Comment: Yes, I recognize that.  I made a mistake on my end... however, this does not work, as `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'kwargs' referenced before assignment`

Comment: The superficial fix would be `nonlocal kwargs`, but you should probably change more than that - multiple calls to `__init__` are sharing and mutating a single `kwargs` dict in an unsafe way. (Also, moving that code into `wrapper` doesn't delay it enough - if you want it to run when `__init__` runs, it needs to be moved into `wrapped`.)